# Music notes (do ré mi)

Tags: musique

How are the names for music notes used in French?

I understand that C=do, D=ré, etc.

But there are two things that remain unclear:

1. The usage of do vs. ut and si vs. ti.
2. The usage of alternative vowels for semitones, e.g. *di* for C-sharp instead of *do*.

To what extent are the different versions used and what text would be expected of me if I am asked to sing a melody from a sheet to prove my note-reading skills?

Comment: To be noted: "Note" is feminine "Une note", whereas notes are masculine: "Donne moi un la".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, as Joubarc said the names are *do*, *ré*, *mi*, *fa*, *sol*, *la* and *si*.

We modulate them with *double bémol* , *bémol* ♭, *bécarre* ♮, *dièse* ♯ and *double dièse* .

*Ut* is nowadays only used in rare expressions like *clef d’ut* (musical C clef)    or *concerto en ut majeur* or *contre-ut* (a high-pitched C in the soprano register).

*di* or *ti* are not used at least in France. Maybe in Canada, Switzerland or Belgium it exists, but that is not standard.

Comment: Et tu dis "mi double bemol"?

Comment: @thei: oui, *mi double bémol*.

Comment: I'm no musician, but as far as I know, *di* and *ti* are not used in Canada.

Comment: ti is actually used in English when using do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, ti, do... to name (and sing) the degrees, regardless of their real values.

Comment: Never heard “ti” in (French-speaking) Belgium.

Answer (score 12):

*Ut* is the old name used for *do* and only found in a few musical expressions such as *clef d'ut* (C major).

The origin of French/Latin musical notes is quite interesting actually. [They are famously taken from the first syllables of a poem in Latin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origine_du_nom_des_notes_de_musique):

> **Ut** queant laxis
>
> **Re**.sonare fibris
>
> **Mi**.ra gestorum
>
> **Fa**.muli tuorum
>
> **Sol**.ve polluti
>
> **La**.bii reatum
>
> **S**.ancte **I**.ohannes

*Ut* was eventually replaced for practical reasons (hard to enunciate when reading a partition aloud) by a [Giovanni Battista Doni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Battista_Doni), who used his own name as an inspiration for the new name.

I have never heard of such a thing as *di* for *do dièse*...

*Ti* was once suggested (*dixit* [Wikipedia En](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note)) as a replacement for *si* (in order to have all notes starting with a different letter), but never widely adopted as far as I know.

Comment: ti is actually used in English when using do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, ti, do... to name (and sing) the degrees, regardless of their real values.

Comment: @François: Thanks for your input, but do you have a source for this? I have very rarely heard the French/Latin names used in English (always 'A', 'B', 'C' etc)...

Comment: my wife has been doing quite a bit of sight-singing here in the US and that's what they used. You can also look in wikipedia for _movable do_ in [Solfège](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solfège) and also [Solmization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solmization)

Comment: by the way you have a mention of this in the last paragraph at the end of your wiki reference.

Answer (score 7):

The notes are as follow:

> *do* (C), *ré* (D), *mi* (E), *fa* (F), *sol* (G), *la* (A), *si* (B).

*ut* is a synonym for *do* but it's not used that much as far as I know.

I've never heard of "ti" and I'm pretty much sure it doesn't exist.

"Sharp" is *dièse* and is used after the note, so a C sharp would be a *do dièse*.
Similary, "Flat" is *bémol*, so a C flat would be… a B… bad example. A E flat is a *mi bémol*.

See also [*Note de musique*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_de_musique) and [*Désignation des notes de musique suivant la langue*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9signation_des_notes_de_musique_suivant_la_langue) on Wikipédia.

Comment: "ti" is used in English, not in French. You can also mention "bécard".

Comment: I refuse to even admit I understand bécarre. It's like you would have a spécial "unshift" key to type lowercase letters when your caps lock is on. That said, Benoit mentionned it already.

Comment: @Joubarc: It is reasonable to say that sharps in musical notation have a limited caps-lock feature. The point is that I have indeed followed conversations in French of the type "You have to sing an F, not an F."

Comment: @Joubard: thanks for fixing my typo ;-) Bécarres are very useful though :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound like I was serious? Of course it's useful. For musicians. Which I'm not, and that's why I had even forgotten it existed.

Comment: You don't mention `di` (for C#) in your answer, I've never come across that.

Comment: I've never heard of alternative vowels either.

Comment: @Joubarc I know you were joking but the Shift key actually doubles as an Unshift key when Caps Lock is on. Try it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Both answers by Benoit and Dave are correct.
They are only missing on the *ti* explanation.

***ti*** is actually used in English when using *do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, ti, do*... to name (and sing) the degrees of the key, regardless of their real values. It's called *Movable Do*.

For instance in D (Ré majeur) the scale would be

- do:  D (ré)
- re:  E (mi)
- mi:  F#(fa dièse)
- fa:  G (sol)
- sol: A (la)
- la:  B (si)
- ti:  C#(do dièse)
- do:  D (ré)
- ...